BIOS don't start on two motherboard after blue screen
I've got a computer with a Esonic H61 motherboard, intel i5, 2x4GB RAM and a ASUS NVIDIA GEFORCE GT710 with a SSD with Ubuntu 22.04 in single boot. A week ago I tried changing SSD with one with dual boot Windows 10+Ubuntu 20.04 (to play a game that works only on Windows and that perfectly works on another very less performer computer) and after a Blue Screen of Death I restored the SSD with Ubuntu 22.04. The first time the motherboard didn't show anything (black screen) with HDMI connected to graphics card so I used the HDMI port on motherboard and it went ok. When I powered the pc off and then turn it on again the screen started not working (it shows "no signal" both with HDMI ans VGA without shows any logo or word, as if the BIOS wouldn't start). It also seems like the keyboard isn't working anymore (the light of caps lock don't come on). It looks like I don't have access to BIOS. I tried to buy a Nuwo H61 motherboard: as soon as it arrived, attaching the SSD with Ubuntu 22.04 it worked, after attaching the SSD with Windows (and the blue screen) it started to behave like the other card. So now I find myself with two non-working motherboards.
SSD with ubuntu 22.04, the screen and keyboard work (I checked and I'm using them right now on another pc to write this question).
I tried detaching everything from the motherboard, keeping only the RAM, CPU, SSD and without the video card and front USBs. I tried measuring the power supply voltage with the voltmeter and it corresponds to what the motherboard manual requires.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to recover them?

I don't think so, both SSDs work perfectly on other PCs. I agree with you that the SSD doesn't kill the motherboard, but it's the only constant I've been able to find.

I suppose you already reset the motherboard to factory defaults and troubleshot from there? That's often required when replacing drives with OSes already installed...

Yes, I did, but it had never happened to me before so I'm not sure I did it correctly: I took a two-slot jumper cap from "auto_pwr1" jumper and put it on the two pins "clr_cmos" jumper, waited and then put it back in the same position as before on "auto_pwr1" jumper. Is  that right?
